# treemap sorting sequence with key and value

Tags: android, treemap

My code as below and the output for treeMapMem as below :-

```
key value
1   a
10  b
2   c
3   d

for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : treeMapMem.entrySet()) {
String value = entry.getValue();
myMenulistSeqMem.add(value);
}
```

My problem like this the sorting sequence is fine from 1,2,3 but 10 appear after 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the default String `Comparator` uses [**lexicographical** order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) -- i.e. character by character, as in a dictionary. Since "1" comes before "2", any String starting with "1" will precede any other starting with "2".

You *could* create your own custom comparator to implement [Natural Sorting](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) and supply it to the [`TreeMap`'s constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20K%3E%29), but in this case it would be far simpler to just define the map as `TreeMap<Integer, String>`.